Is not possible to apply window for batch processing in flink 1.20 for DataStream APIs
I'm working on flink app, which should be doing Batch processing. My plan is to enable stream processing on the same app. Meanwhile, I was trying to enable window for datastream, but nothing is printed on the console.
The code is as follows:
avroStream
.windowAll(TumblingProcessTimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(60)))
.process(new ProcessAllWindowFunction<GenericRecord,GenericRecord,TimeWindow>() {
@Override
public void process(PorcessAllWindowFunction<GenericRecord,GenericRecord,Timewindow>.Context context, Iterable<GenericRecord> elements, Collector<GenericRecord> out) throws Exception {
// some processing
}
}).print();

Why isn't it happening?
I expect the data after processing should be printed on the stdout of the flink UI.

Are you running some test data through this workflow, and not seeing any result?
